# A ribbon presentation for a torus knot

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $K$ be a knot in $S^3$. It is well-known that the knot $K \# -\overline{K}$ is always ribbon.

The following picture describes the connected sum of the left-handed torus knot $T(3,4)$ and the right-handed torus knot $T(3,4)$. In Rolfsen's notation, $T(3,4) = 8_{19}$, for several descriptions see [[1]](http://katlas.org/wiki/8_19) and [[2]](https://knotinfo.math.indiana.edu/diagram_display.php?8_19).

I would like to find the ribbon move(s) for this composite knot but I could not elaborate.

Is there an easy way to see this or any trick to figure out the necessary ribbon moves?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find a set of ribbon moves, then you need to end up with an unlink with several components; therefore, you need to attack crossings!

This is your diagram:

[image]

Then I add two bands along twists of given torus knots:

[image]

Next, we have a link with three components:

[image]

If you apply Reidemeister moves, you may eventually find an unlink with three components:

[image]

There is no specific trick for any torus knot (my opinion) but you can control the number of additional ribbon moves.

Assume that $p$ and $q$ are relatively coprime integers with $p < q$. Then for the corresponding ribbon knot $T(p,q) \# \overline{T(p,q)} $, the number of ribbon bands is $p-1$.

Answer (score 5):

As this composite knot is an example of a symmetric union of knots I suggest that you read my paper "[The search for nonsymmetric ribbon knots](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.06909.pdf)" (see for instance Figures 1 and 4 and the explanation in the text).